# Short Story about a man who does a perfect job the first time he tries each task

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm pretty sure I read it either at the end of the 1990s or the very beginning of 2000. I think it was a first-person narration. The character involved learned that he could succeed at any task he put his mind to, but only the very first time. I think he initially figured it out when he threw a bullseye in darts and then couldn't hit the broad side of the barn. He tries to make use of his gift, but continuously fails because he can only ever do a thing perfectly once. Ultimately:

> He meets a girl, falls completely in love with her and has perfect sex... only to realize that it can never be that good again. The story ended with him lifting a gun to his head and grimly thinking that, since this was the first time, he couldn't miss.

I have this vague idea that this was tied into mutants in some way. I think I read the story online, so I don't have an anthology to attach it to, although it might have been published in print as well.

Comment: What makes this an SFF story? Is it that his 'beginner's luck' ability is supernatural?

Comment: It was definitely unnatural. As I said, I have this vague idea that he had recognized himself as a mutant and that others had powers, just that his was... underwhelming.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it. "[Beginner's Luck](http://web.archive.org/web/20061112225415/http://www.subreality.com/tcp/begluck.htm)", part of [The Common People](http://fanlore.org/wiki/Common_People) archive, a selection of X-Men fanfiction that was intended to look at mutants who were not superheroes or supervillains and largely did not interact with the canonical characters.

> I toss the dart at the board, from where I'm sitting, all the way across the other side of the room. I'm drunk, I'm messing about. And yeah, I know it's stupid to throw sharp objects around, but when you've had a few pints, who really gives a shit, right?
>
> And then I feel something -- I dunno -- *click* -- inside me, just as the dart leaves my hand. It hits the bullseye. And the crowd goes wild...

....

> But one pattern is clear from the beginning: it only ever happens the first time. Just the first time. After that, I have to rely on my normal talents, and they aren't exactly up there, know what I mean?

....

> Beautiful, perfect, amazing Gwen. I fall like a rock, and -- maybe it was my power, I don't know -- but somehow she falls for me too. And we're perfect together. We talk together. We laugh, endlessly. She gets on with all my mates, God help her. I even like her parents, and bizarrely enough, they like me too. God looks down and smiles on us. And then we make love -- and it *is* making love, something I never really did before with anyone, even before my powers.

....

> But then -- then it's the second time, and it's -- ordinary. The earth still moves, I mean, if I wasn't constantly comparing it to the first time, it would seem pretty special to me. But I feel sick inside, as if I've cheated her somehow, and I try to find the words to apologise. She just laughs at me, holds me tight, says, "Shut up, you fool. It was wonderful. Christ Ted, it can't be *completely* perfect, every time."

....

> So I bought a gun today, and I spent an hour polishing it, and cleaning it, and making sure that everything was in full working order.
>
> 'Cos you know, I've never tried to kill myself before.
>
> And I want to be sure and get it exactly right.
>
> First time.

Comment: Wow. I see why this was hard to find. Now I can stop trying :-)